# What is the best way to clear time using Moment.js?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

What is the best way to clear time of a browser native date object using Moment.js so that in the current timezone of my browser it's today midnight.

Comment: Maybe [`startOf('day')`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @VincenzoC - Please provide answers in answer, not in comments.

Comment: Sebastien - Keep in mind that not every local day *has* a midnight.  If there is a DST "spring-forward" transition at 00:00, then the day starts at 01:00.  This happens in Brazil, and several other places around the world.  `startOf('day')` will reflect that.

Comment: @MattJohnson you are right, but I was not sure that I understood what the OP was asking and just tried to give a quick link. I think that a good answer has to include consideration like what you added in the second comment (I was not aware of the _spring-forward_ "issue" with midnight)

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing to what you asked is as follows:

```
var d = new Date();                // your browser native date object
var m = moment(d).startOf('day');  // move to the start of the day in the local time zone
d = m.toDate();                    // convert back to a native date object
```

However, if this is the only thing you want to do, you don't need Moment.  Just do:

```
d = d.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Also, keep in mind that not every local day has a midnight. If there is a DST "spring-forward" transition at 00:00, then the day starts at 01:00. This happens in Brazil, and several other places around the world.  In this case, Moment's `startOf('day')` function will ensure the result is 1:00, however the `setHours` approach may set 1:00, or may set 23:00 on the prior day, depending on browser implementation.